# Heaviside function & Integral Limits

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, special-functions, laplace-transform

When considering integration, how does one use the Heaviside function in order to alter the limits of integration. For example

If i have
$$ \int_a^b f(x) dx $$
But want to change this integral to be over the range, for example $0$ to $\infty$, then how do i use the Heaviside to this?

From what i understand about graphing, H(x) is the line $y=1$ that begins at $0$ and goes to $+\infty$, or in this case $a$ to $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_a^b{f(x)dx}=\int_a^{b}{f(x)[H(x-a)-H(x-b)]dx}=\int_0^{\infty}{f(x)[H(x-a)-H(x-b)]dx}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you arrived at this conclusion?

Comment: If $H(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $H(x)=1$ for $x>0$ then we have that $H(x-a)=0$   for $x<a$ and $H(x)=1$ for $x>a$ (similarly for $b$). Thus, $H(x-a)-H(x-b)=0$ for $x\in(-\infty,a)\cup(b,\infty)$ and  $H(x-a)-H(x-b)=1$ for $x\in(a,b)$.

Comment: Is $H(x−a)−H(x−b)=H(b-x)H(x−a)$, if so i understand.

Comment: @MathsPro Yes you can write it also like that.

Comment: As a final question, if one of the limits is already okay, i can just add the other? i.e if $b=\infty$ then i can just multiply the function by H(x-a)

Comment: @MathsPro Yes, correct.